# How to write a program to concatenate two strings character by character. e.g : JOHN + SMITH = JSOMHINTH

Tags: php, string, compare

This is my code but it only gives results if both strings are of same length. But what if I want to compare strings of different lengths?

```
<?php

  $n1 = "Apple";
  $n2 = "Orang";

  //count length fo both string 
  $count1 = strlen($n1);
  $count2 = strlen($n2);
  $finalcount = 0;

  if($count1 > $count2) {
    $finalcount = $count1;
  } elseif ($count1 < $count2) {
    $finalcount = $count2;
  } else {
    $finalcount = $count1;
  }

  //convert string to array
  $n1 = str_split($n1);
  $n2 = str_split($n2);

  $i = 0;
  $result = "";
  for($i = 0;$i < $finalcount  ; $i++) {
    $result = $result .$n1[$i] . $n2[$i];
  }

  echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: When will the code enter the `else` part?

Comment: Share a sample input and what the output should be. Your code makes very little sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way to do it (some explanation in the comments):

```
<?php

$str = 'test';
$str2 = 'test2';

$arr = str_split($str);
$arr2 = str_split($str2);

// Find the longest string
$max = max(array(strlen($str), strlen($str2)));

$result = '';

for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
    // Check if array key exists. If so, add it to result
    if (array_key_exists($i, $arr)){
        $result .= $arr[$i];
    }

    if (array_key_exists($i, $arr2)){
        $result .= $arr2[$i];
    }
}

echo $result; //tteesstt2

?>
```

Comment: without using predefined functions..Is it possible to do this? and how can to do this?

Comment: @hearthacker What do you mean with _"Without using predefined functions"_? There aren't any predefined functions in this code that solve the question at hand. Each "predefined function" you see here is just normal PHP that does something completely unrelated to the question itself. It's just the combination of all that leads to the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is exactly what you are looking for: 
[PHP - Merge two strings](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/merge-two-strings.htm)

```
/**
 * Merges two strings in a way that a pattern like ABABAB will be
 * the result.
 *
 * @param     string    $str1   String A
 * @param     string    $str2   String B
 * @return    string    Merged string
 */  
function MergeBetween($str1, $str2){

    // Split both strings
    $str1 = str_split($str1, 1);
    $str2 = str_split($str2, 1);

    // Swap variables if string 1 is larger than string 2
    if (count($str1) >= count($str2))
        list($str1, $str2) = array($str2, $str1);

    // Append the shorter string to the longer string
    for($x=0; $x < count($str1); $x++)
        $str2[$x] .= $str1[$x];

    return implode('', $str2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

// Write a program to concatenate two strings character by 
// character. e.g : JOHN + SMITH  = JSOMHINTH

echo "\nstring 1 : ".$string1="JOHN";
echo "\nstring 2 : ".$string2="SMITH";

$firstArray=str_split($string1);
$secondArray=str_split($string2);

if(count($firstArray)>count($secondArray)) {
  $loop=count($firstArray);
}
else {
  $loop=count($secondArray);
}

$result=[];
$i=0;
while($i<$loop) {
  isset($firstArray[$i])?array_push($result,$firstArray[$i]):'';
  isset($secondArray[$i])?array_push($result,$secondArray[$i]):'';
  $i++;
}
echo "\nResult String : ".implode($result);

?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).